# How to reconnect to Openfire server after unlocking the iPhone screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, openfire, xmppframework

I am using [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework). My XMPP connection is always closed when I locked the iPhone screen.
I need to reconnect to my [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) server when I unlock the screen.

Here is how I used `XMPPReconnect` (in Swift):

```
func xmppStreamDidAuthenticate(sender: XMPPStream) {
    let xmppReconnect = XMPPReconnect()
    xmppReconnect.activate(sender)
    xmppReconnect.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
}
```

However, it seems it never reconnects when I unlock the screen.
Am I using `XMPPReconnect` correctly?

How do I achieve my target?

Comment: What is an open fire server?  Please provide a link or update your tags.

Comment: OpenFire: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write code in your appdelegate in applicationDidBecomeActive. becuase when you unlock the screen this method will call, and in this method you have to call connect method to openfire....

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
       self.connect()
    }

 func connect() -> Bool {
        println("connecting")
        setupStream()


        var jabberID: String? = "YOUR_JID" 
        var myPassword: String? = "YOUR_PASSWORD" 
        var server: String? = "YOUR_HOST" 




        xmppStream!.hostName = "YOURHOST_NAME"
        xmppStream!.hostPort = 5222

        if let stream = xmppStream {
            if !stream.isDisconnected() {
                return true
            }

            if jabberID == nil || myPassword == nil {
                println("no jabberID set:" + "\(jabberID)")
                println("no password set:" + "\(myPassword)")
                return false
            }

            stream.myJID = XMPPJID.jidWithString(jabberID)
            password = myPassword

            var error: NSError?
            if !stream.connectWithTimeout(XMPPStreamTimeoutNone, error: &error) {
                var alertView: UIAlertView? = UIAlertView(title:"Error", message: "Cannot connect to \(error!.localizedDescription)", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
                alertView!.show()

                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Hope this will help!